# Is 20 MB Document size limit in couchdb inclusive of attachment size?

Tags: couchdb

I read about 20MB limit on document size on couchbase and 20MB limit on attachment size. I want to know if attachments added to a document add up to total size of that document. I think it is not inclusive but couldn't find any reference to it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, under what circumstances does it make sense for a document to even *approach* that size?

Comment: Attachments such as images can easily be around 5 MB. Therefore if I have 5 images as attachments in my document and if attachments do add up to overall size of the document then document's size would cross the 20MB mark.

Comment: I think my use case is a little vague here. I am **NOT** storing images directly as properties in a document. I am saving it as attachments (the way couchbase recommends). My question was if all the attachments associated with a document add up to size of the document. All this started with a small discussion in my workplace regarding the same. Some people believed that because of a 20MB size limit to every document, we can not add more than 5 images. We believed that could never be the case. I looked online for clarification but did not find anything. @Flimzy has given a nice answer below.

Comment: I see his answer below, but it is applicable to a different product (I'm not saying it's wrong, but you should be aware that Couchdb is NOT Couchbase, despite the moniker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question recently changed, actually. From the [CouchDB 2.1.0 release notes](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/whatsnew/2.1.html) you can see:

> The new `httpd/max_http_request_size` configuration parameter was added. This has the same behavior as the old `couchdb/max_document_size` configuration parameter, which had been unfortunately misnamed, and has now been updated to behave as the name would suggest. Both are documented in the shipped `default.ini` file.

So the answer to your question depends on which version of CouchDB you're using.  With CouchDB 2.0.x and earlier, the limit was actually related to the HTTP request size, which means that the effectual document size limit could be somewhat lower, depending on how the document was transmitted.

As of 2.1.0, however, the [new description](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/config/couchdb.html#couchdb/max_document_size) applies:

> Limit maximum document body size. Size is calculated based on the serialized Erlang representation of the JSON document body, because that reflects more accurately the amount of storage consumed on disk.

Since the serialized Erlang representation of the JSON document does not contain attachments, it is a safe assumption that this limit does not include attachments.

I have just [updated the CouchDB documentation](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-documentation/pull/218) to explain this explicitly, as well.